Unable to install numpy through terminal using pip
I'm trying to install the python package numpy with no luck. I'm using pip install numpy in the terminal, but it returns the following error message:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/numpy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

I do have pip installed properly, and is currently using Python 3.11.2. Any ideas on what is happening here and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

What OS are you on? Are you trying to install numpy into the global environment, or did you create a virtual environment? Is pip install numpy all you're entering, with no other packages previously installed? And is the output you shared (it would be helpful if you edited your question to be a bit less messy and use formatting for the output) all the output you're seeing?

If you have multiple versions of python installed you could see this. Try below command python -m pip install numpy
